# Azure AD B2C Idp initiated sign-in not working

Tags: saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, idp

I am trying to enable Idp initiated SSO within my SAML B2C custom policy however it doesn't appear to be working. I have SP initiated SSO working fine however when attempting to load the login URL https://example.b2clogin.com/te/example.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_samlsignin/samlp/sso/login I just get the generic error:

"Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.
Correlation ID: fee21b5e-4d30-419c-b5d5-6423ac400ed5
Timestamp: 2019-09-26 09:17:54Z
AADB2C: An exception has occurred."

As per the instruction found in [Is iDP initiated SSO supported with a custom SAML iDP in Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079978/is-idp-initiated-sso-supported-with-a-custom-saml-idp-in-azure-ad-b2c) and the referenced Microsoft article I have set the following metadata tag in the profile

```
<Metadata>
       <Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item>
</Metadata>
```

I am pushing the output to Application Insights which is providing the error:

"HttpRequest does not contain any SAML 2.0 protocol parameters"

Does anyone know how I can permit SAML Idp initiated SSO within a B2C policy?

Comment: how does your policy looks like ???

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54079978/9922. Note that this is IDP Initiated with B2C as an RP. I don't believe B2C as a SAML IDP is currently supported.

Comment: @nzpcmad. thanks for pointing that out. it appears I didnt read that post correctly. I'll reach out the Microsoft to see if this is technically possible in B2C

Comment: Some research shows that B2C as a SAML IDP is in preview - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp

Comment: But not clear that this supports IDP Initiated.

Answer (score 2):

B2C was not able to parse the request sent to it successfully. Please make sure that you request is correctly encoded ([How do I correctly prepare an 'HTTP Redirect Binding' SAML Request using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090403/how-do-i-correctly-prepare-an-http-redirect-binding-saml-request-using-c-sharp) talks about sending hhtp redirect message correctly) . Also it seems you are sending an samlp/sso/login request. So this scenario is SP initiated login

Answer (score 2):

I reached out to MS regarding this and it appears that Idp initiated SSO is not yet possible:

> Per checking with our product team, that the IDP-initiated SSO is not supported for SAML authentication now in AAD B2C service. For Azure AD B2C to work with SAML, you may refer to the information below:
>   https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp
>   https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp/blob/master/saml-rp-spec.md
>
> And currently they haven’t gotten a chance to allow IDP-initiated SSO with azure AD B2C workflow. I will further check with our product team to see if they have any further information/suggestion on how to deal with this scenario, however, I could not promise if there is any for now.
>
> Meanwhile, you are welcome to provide your feedbacks about allowing IDP-initiated SSO for azure AD B2C here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory, our product team will regularly monitor the site and take the valuable ideas from here.

More details can be found in the comment of the feature request https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334323-saml-protocol-support

Hopefully this helps anyone else after the same thing.